# i18next changing resGetPath on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, i18next

I have a node application which uses the i18next module to handle i18n, but I'm having one problem that I can't seem to solve on the server side.

The application is built in `node` and uses the `express` framework.

In the main `app.js` file that is the entry point for the ap I require the `i18n` module and run the `init` method.

This is to set it up for use on the client side.

Later on in a different file I am trying to reset the `resGetPath` property in order to load a translation file in a different location to the normal ones (some files are located in the default `locales/__lng__/__ns__.json` path, others are in their own separate folders).

I can't seem to find a specific method on the `i18n` object to do this so I have been trying to just run the `init` method again with the callback.

However even if I do this the `resGetPath` property is not changed and it doesn't pick up the translation strings from the new files.

If I set the `resGetPath` property in the first `init` call in `app.js` though it works as expected (although then it loses the normal translations in `locales/__lng__/__ns__.json`)

Basically this is what I'm trying to do:

`app.js`

```
i18n.init({
  detectLngQS: 'lang',
  debug: false,
  useCookie: false,
  detectLngFromHeaders: true,
  fallbackLng: ['en-GB', 'dev']
});
```

`after-app.js`

```
i18n.init({
  resGetPath: path.join(__dirname, '../new-path.json')
}, function(t) {
  // Here `t` does not get the strings in the new resGetPath
});
```

Can anybody tell me how to change `resGetPath` on the fly, or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

You just have to run `i18n.sync.resStore = {}` before you run `init`, then it will force a reload.